# Why doesn't some materializecss animations/dropdown menu work in chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a website that uses materializecss and it works fine. The animations and everything work normally.

I am making a chrome extension and it is not the case there. Some form animations don't work and I tried using adding another css library called semantic-ui for dropdowns and clicking on the dropdown does nothing. Hell, w3school's dropdown code doesn't work either.

**popup.html:**

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**styles.css**

```
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */
.show {display:block;}
```

Comment: did you check if you have javascript enabled on your Chrome ?

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif yes, also, my other js scripts are working fine

Comment: Right click the popup and click inspect: you'll see an error in the devtools console because inline js is not allowed in html of extensions. There could be other errors in your code.

Comment: There is a restriction to run inline js in chrome extensions (such as `onclick`). Just move you click handler into a separate `.js` file and it starts to work fine.